# Should I remove 0 values when calculating the average of many simulation runs?

Tags: mean, simulation

Let's say I have a simulation model with stages A, B, C. I want to calculate the average time of each stage over 1000 runs as they contain stochastics. In many runs, either one of these stages may not be interacted with, and therefore, contain a time of 0, drastically lowering the mean of that stage.

When calculating the average of a stage, should I include the 0 values that are present? To my knowledge, these 0's are technically null values and should not be included.

Comment: They are different distributions. If you want "the average time spent doing A, conditional on A being required at all", exclude them. If you want the unconditional expectation, you need to include them. If you're looking for the average time of the whole process whether each stage is required or not (maybe A + maybe B + maybe C), you're looking for the unconditional expectation and you need to include them. Which did you want?

Comment: To understand how long each stage takes, I assume that I would only want to take the average of the times in which that stage was actually processing time by being interacted with. So I believe it would be conditional.